# Is there a simple way to enable collision with geometry nodes?

Tags: node-editor, geometry, collision

new to geometry node, in the exemple below im trying to make the curves, instanced on points on the mesh going along the surface of the objets, the stripes are animated with a fake wind effect (wave texture with offset). After reasearching a lot I'm starting to think it's impossible...

Any idea how to make that ?
Thanks you.

[image: Exemple]

[image]

Comment: As far as I understand, collisions with the currently available simulaton zone and other nodes, is stupidly complicated. There aren't much resources around and there are not many people whom we can learn from right now coz most people are learning these things themselves. For your case, a system like whether a point is at a distance from the mesh and if not push it away will probably work. But this might be complicated to set up if you are not too familiar with all the nodes. I myself am learning all this stuff and collisions are the most frustrating things that I face. Please wait for someone

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will post an update If I find how to do it